# Change Session in runtime configuration

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4

In `app/config/session.php` we have `'lifetime' => 120,` for application session.

I want to change that in user login and I want to customizable with how user login in to system.

How to change that handly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it

```
Config::set('session.lifetime', '200');
```

before creating a session

Comment: before creating a session? laravel set that default. how to create before that?

Comment: Yes it takes it as default. But the sessions you will use on future will also have the same lifetime. When you want to customize it you will have to change the 'config' code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Config::set('session.lifetime', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.env** file to change session lifetime on Laravel 10.x.

```
SESSION_LIFETIME = 120 // 60 * 24 * 365 = 525600 minutes (1 year)
```